# cocos2d-js Adding a Sprite to a Menu

Tags: javascript, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-android, cocos2d-js, cocos2d-x-2.x

I currently trying to write  simple menu. So far i can add menu fonts to the menu, but when i try to add sprites, the sprites don't appear.

```
    var normalImage = new cc.Sprite.create(res.tv_png);
    var menuItem1 = new cc.MenuItemFont("Item1", hat);
    var menuItem2 = new cc.MenuItemFont("Item2", jacket);
    var item = cc.MenuItemSprite.create(normalImage);   
    var menu = new cc.Menu(menuItem1,menuItem2,item);
    menu.alignItemsVertically();
    this.addChild(menu);
```

Comment: I don't know cocos2d-js, but there is no `new` in the `var item = cc.MenuItemSprite.create(normalImage);` line.

Comment: or you can do it like this:  `var normalImage = new cc.Sprite(res.tv_png);`

Answer (score 0):

You don't see your sprite because `MenuItemSprite` constructor requires selected sprite to init itself. Also you better don't use `new` and `create` simultaneously. The `create` method is deprecated.

```
var normalImage = new cc.Sprite(res.tv_png);
var selectedImage = new cc.Sprite(res.tv_png);
var menuItem1 = new cc.MenuItemFont("Item1", hat);
var menuItem2 = new cc.MenuItemFont("Item2", jacket);
var item = new cc.MenuItemSprite(normalImage, selectedImage);   
var menu = new cc.Menu(menuItem1, menuItem2, item);
menu.alignItemsVertically();
this.addChild(menu);
```